# how to remove the edge of an image after edge extraction using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I have an image in gray scale and I would like to remove the edge that is extracted by using an edge extraction method in MATLAB.

Is it possible to do it?

Below is my code that perform the edge extraction ：

```
%load the image
A=imread('MikuBW.jpg');   

%predefined edge extraction method in MATLAB
g=edge(A,'canny');

%plot results
subplot(2,1,1);
imshow(A),title('ORIGINAL');

subplot(2,1,2);
imshow(g),title('CANNY');
```

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGa2H.jpg) [the result of original image and after edge extraction][1]

how do I remove the edge that is extracted in "CANNY" from the original image?

thank you for any help possible! =)

Comment: Hi wesley, when you say that you want to remove the edge from the image, what exactly do you mean? do you simply want to put their zeros instead, or do you want something more complex?

Comment: @drorco thank you for the reply, I want the "CANNY" part of the original image to be removed

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the "Canny" part to be removed, i.e. to be replaced with zeros, you can simply write:

```
A(g) = 0;
```

however, a more "natural" approach will be to blur the image, so it will have less edges in the first place:

```
H = fspecial('disk',5);
A = imfilter(A,H,'replicate');
```

Comment: For making the former edges white, set A(g)=255;

Comment: That is nonsense. Replacing Canny pixels with either black or white will just move the edge by 1 pixel or leave it the same as you again introduce a high gradient transition...
The only proper way to "remove" a pixel is replacing it by an interpolation of its sourrounding.

Comment: @Piglet - it depends on what is the desired output.  I also added a suggestion for blurring the image - it will acchieve the result which you are talking about